# How to convert from PostgreSQL to GeoJSON format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I have a simple table called"imposm3_restaurant" with columns [ id, name, geometry] I want to convert these data into geoJSON, I am using this function

```
CREATE VIEW imposm3_restaurants_geojson AS SELECT row_to_json(fc) AS geojson FROM 
(SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f))
As features FROM 
(SELECT 
'Feature' As type, 
ST_AsGeoJSON((lg.geometry),15,0)::json As geometry,
row_to_json((id, name)) As properties
FROM imposm3_restaurants As lg) As f ) As fc;
```

and the result is this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2615020.47191046,5899232.25158985],[2615034.50527113,5899231.67978097],[2615033.86145338,5899215.4513157],[2615032.35921198,5899215.51938806],[2615031.96732292,5899205.64890158],[2615034.97180572,5899205.51275702],[2615034.36531075,5899190.07397728],[2615018.19522163,5899190.71385561],[2615018.77372453,5899205.40384137],[2615020.47191046,5899205.32215463],[2615020.91045298,5899216.48601561],[2615019.83742341,5899216.52685903],[2615020.47191046,5899232.25158985]]},"properties":{"f1":2719,"f2":"Atelierul de Pizza"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[2615018.19522163,5899190.71385561],[2615018.77372453,5899205.40384137],[2615020.47191046,5899205.32215463],[2615020.91045298,5899216.48601561],[2615019.83742341,5899216.52685903],[2615020.47191046,5899232.25158985],[2615034.50527113,5899231.67978097],[2615033.86145338,5899215.4513157],[2615032.35921198,5899215.51938806],[2615031.96732292,5899205.64890158],[2615034.97180572,5899205.51275702],[2615034.36531075,5899190.07397728],[2615018.19522163,5899190.71385561]]]},"properties":{"f1":2720,"f2":"Atelierul de Pizza"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2624875.82864931,5903443.39761349],[2624897.49451598,5903452.78251964],[2624901.44139867,5903443.67003443],[2624879.78486269,5903434.29875908],[2624875.82864931,5903443.39761349]]},"properties":{"f1":2986,"f2":"Pizza Acrobatica"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[2624875.82864931,5903443.39761349],[2624897.49451598,5903452.78251964],[2624901.44139867,5903443.67003443],[2624879.78486269,5903434.29875908],[2624875.82864931,5903443.39761349]]]},"properties":{"f1":2988,"f2":"Pizza Acrobatica"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2622460.22447654,5904586.41424973],[2622479.10046632,5904587.95362911],[2622480.25747212,5904573.81314552],[2622461.39081303,5904572.26014582],[2622460.22447654,5904586.41424973]]},"properties":{"f1":3248,"f2":"Casa Vikingilor"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[2622460.22447654,5904586.41424973],[2622479.10046632,5904587.95362911],[2622480.25747212,5904573.81314552],[2622461.39081303,5904572.26014582],[2622460.22447654,5904586.41424973]]]},"properties":{"f1":3249,"f2":"Casa Vikingilor"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2625201.09657005,5897608.45120294],[2625224.46062264,5897614.30435379],[2625241.33051365,5897576.653689],[2625213.43174478,5897570.82778714],[2625201.09657005,5897608.45120294]]},"properties":{"f1":6152,"f2":"Silva"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[2625201.09657005,5897608.45120294],[2625224.46062264,5897614.30435379],[2625241.33051365,5897576.653689],[2625213.43174478,5897570.82778714],[2625201.09657005,5897608.45120294]]]},"properties":{"f1":6153,"f2":"Silva"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2622825.25980629,5904372.27967993],[2622826.15555271,5904353.45341631],[2622834.51585268,5904353.1673446],[2622854.22227404,5904346.00193242],[2622860.03529512,5904362.26715407],[2622856.61093118,5904374.66361634],[2622825.25980629,5904372.27967993]]},"properties":{"f1":6322,"f2":"Restaurant Sinaia"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[2622825.25980629,5904372.27967993],[2622856.61093118,5904374.66361634],[2622860.03529512,5904362.26715407],[2622854.22227404,5904346.00193242],[2622834.51585268,5904353.1673446],[2622826.15555271,5904353.45341631],[2622825.25980629,5904372.27967993]]]},"properties":{"f1":6323,"f2":"Restaurant Sinaia"}}]}
```

which does not have a current geometry, do you know what is wrong in function: I am using Postgres 9.3 and PostGIS 2.2

Comment: What do you mean with "does not have a current geometry"? The result has linestring geometries

Comment: actually, I want to display the result on the map, when I input the data into http://geojson.io/#map=6/48.538/2620094.370 nothing display. what is my mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your output is a valid geojson file but the geometries are projected using the projection [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/).

You can load the data without problems in the most gis desktop applications, in example Quantum Gis.

Probably geojson.io supports only long/lat coordinates [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/), also try reprojecting the geometries to long/lat coordinates using the function [St_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html)

Change this line:

```
ST_AsGeoJSON((lg.geometry),15,0)::json As geometry,
```

in this:

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(lg.geometry, 4326),15,0)::json As geometry,
```