# Converting PostGIS table (postgresql) to GeoJSON

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geojson

I visited the question showed in [How to convert from PostgreSQL to GeoJSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388451/how-to-convert-from-postgresql-to-geojson-format/56150304#56150304)

This PostGIS SQL transforms the whole table into a GeoJSON result:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) AS geojson FROM 
(SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f))
As features FROM 
(SELECT 
'Feature' As type, 
ST_AsGeoJSON((lg.geometry),15,0)::json As geometry,
row_to_json((id, name)) As properties
FROM imposm3_restaurants As lg) As f ) As fc;
```

I've found there that in the results, we don't get the name of the fields.

I expect the output as
 "properties":{"id":6323,"name":"Restaurant Sinaia"

but the actual output is
 "properties":{"f1":6323,"f2":"Restaurant Sinaia"

I read the specification of the row_to_json instruction, so I decided to change the last row_to_json instruction

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) AS geojson FROM 
(SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f))
As features FROM 
(SELECT 
'Feature' As type, 
ST_AsGeoJSON((lg.geometry),15,0)::json As geometry,
row_to_json((lg)) As properties
FROM imposm3_restaurants As lg) As f ) As fc;
```

But now the geojson retrieves also the geometry field as a property.

I mean, into the results I can see the geometry formated in geojson format and again in PostGIS format (this second geometry is not necessary, I could waste it) so if the first result is 1200Kb, the second it will be around 2300Kb.

What can I do? any alternatives to

```
row_to_json((id, name)) As properties
```

or

```
row_to_json((lg)) As properties
```

I also tried things like

```
row_to_json(('id',lg.id ,'masa',lg.masa ,'parcela',lg.parcela)) As properties
```

and any others, but with no results (only SQL errors)

Thank you very much

Comment: Oi José! Welcome to SO :-) A few tips for you to improve the chances to get a response: provide a create table statement with some sample data (preferably within an insert), the current output and the expected result. Also, do not forget to post (properly formatted) the error messages every time you get one. Happy coding.

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do, is first select your columns then row_to_json this select.
With your values, this will give following example :

```
SELECT
    row_to_json(fc)
FROM (
    SELECT
        'FeatureCollection' AS type
        , array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
    FROM (
        SELECT
            'feature' AS type
            , ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json as geometry
            , (
                SELECT
                    row_to_json(t)
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        id
                        , name
                    ) AS t
                ) AS properties
        FROM imposm3_restaurants
    ) AS f
) AS fc
```

Comment: This is excellent. It doesn't perform well on my instance, what kind of indexing can be applied to make this quicker? The auto advisor tooling I ran did not make any recommendations. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can use ogr2ogr executing this code in a console

```
cd C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin && ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" C:\Users\Documents\nameFile.json "PG:dbname=nameBD schemas=NameSchema host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='**'" -sql "select * from public.tableName"
```